# Bitbucket and SublimeMerge Compatibility Issue with WSL2 and Git Commits Loading

Tags: javascript, php, docker, bitbucket, sublimemerge

I use Docker along with WSL2, Bitbucket, and SublimeMerge. However, Bitbucket doesn't support a virtual machine like WSL2, and that's a problem because it doesn't load the commits stored in Git. Loading the localhost takes a long time. Can you give me any solution?

I've tried opening VSCode through the local machine;
I searched for documentation on Bitbucket to try to solve it, but I couldn't find anything about this issue.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear how the different pieces of software you've mentioned relate to each other. What are you actually trying to do - host a local copy of the BitBucket website? If so, what do SublimeMerge and VSCode have to do with it?

Comment: _"However, Bitbucket doesn't support a virtual machine like WSL2"_ - Can you expand on this? What exactly are you trying to do that doesn't work? I've fetched/cloned git repos from Bitbucket in WSL2 many times.

Comment: I cloned it to WSL2, everything went well.
However, when I open the work, it does not update the commits on the first attempt, I have to close the project and wait. It takes a long time to load. At times when I commit changes, it asks for the password, I enter it but it shows that I was denied access.

Comment: Can you tell me if the SSH key with BitBucket will solve my problem?

Comment: It's still not clear what exactly you're trying to do - what does "open the work" mean? What takes a long time to load? Can you [edit] the question to give a clear sequence of steps, explaining how the different software you've mentioned is relevant? e.g. "1. I logged into my WSL instance and ran `docker do-magic-stuff`; 2. I opened SublimeMerge and clicked the "reticulate spines" option in the "widgets" menu..." and so on.